# string.format vs + operator for string concatenation

Tags: .net, string

Which is better in respect to performance and memory utilization?

```
// + Operator
oMessage.Subject = "Agreement, # " + sNumber + ", Name: " + sName;

// String.Format
oMessage.Subject = string.Format("Agreement, # {0}, Name: {1}", sNumber, sName);
```

My preference is memory utilization. The + operator is used throughout the application. String.Format and StringBuilder is rarely use. I want to reduce the amount of memory fragmentation caused by excessive string allocations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best option in this specific case is the `+` operator. The compiler will make a call to `String.Concat` out of your code:

```
oMessage.Subject = String.Concat("Agreement, # ", sNumber, ", Name: ",  sName);
```

The `String.Concat` will loop through the strings to determine the total length, allocate a string with that length and copy each string into that. It's the most efficient way of concatenating a bunch of strings.

---

Note: If you are concatenating strings with value types (e.g. integers), you should explicitly convert them to strings. Otherwise they will be boxed, and everything is sent as objects to the `String.Concat` method:

```
oMessage.Subject = "Agreement, # ", iNumber.ToString();
```

Comment: +1 for voting me down and then explaining it much better (and correctly) than I did.

Comment: +1 for this specific case + is the best solution. I was just trying to cover all the bases.

Comment: I wish to note, that in this specific context, the OP is concatenating 4 strings. This is the maximum number of string on which Concat works efficiently. More that 4 strings, the performance of Concat is reduced and other methods like StringBuilder become viable [From DotNetPerls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-concat)

Comment: @Steve: The only thing that happens when you call `String.Concat` with a lot of strings is that they are placed in an array. Creating an array is still a cheaper operation than creating a `StringBuilder` object.

Comment: One of the reasons I asked the question, is that String.Format uses a StringBuilder. So let's removed the performance concern. What is the best in terms of memory allocation?

Comment: @AMissico: The `+` operator is still the best option. It creates a minimum of intermediate objects.